# validating textbox for the specific range value using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i am using javascript validation library file  for validating textbox values. now i want to allow user to enter only value  in between  0 and 9999999.99 . how to do this by using

> $.validator.addMethod
>   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better use jQuery for this, makes it easier (plug and play).

Check out this sample http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/max

Comment: hey thanx for this link,its helpful.but along with this i want min value grater than 0(e.g. 0.70) and i want to validate this for currency(decimal data type) .

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/rangelength#range for range, for the decimal you should play with the code a bit. You can always cast you decimal to int and set 100 as you max

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use ASP.NET Validators?

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rValidator" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="thatControl"
        MaximumValue="9999999.99"
        MinimumValue="0" 
        Type="Double" />
```

Comment: RangeValidators only display an error message :( I need to constrain the values displayed.